# hibernate / Java :Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have these entities classes

PlayerProfileEntity & UserInfoEntity

I have a join on userInfoEntity & PlaterProfileEntity and saving my record in database like this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(PlayerProfileEntity.class);
player.setUserId(new UserInfoEntity());
player.getUserId().setAddress(user.getUserId().getAddress());

session.save(player);
tr.commit();
```

I used this assosiation in my PlayerProfileEntity class

```
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="userid")
private UserInfoEntity userId;
```

I am getting this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cricdb`.`userinfo`, CONSTRAINT `FK_teamInfo` FOREIGN KEY (`teamId`) REFERENCES `teaminfo` (`TeamId`))
```

Any Solution?

Comment: Dunno, but typically you would do something like this: `player.getUser().setAddress(something)`. ie I think you have bigger problems with your model

Comment: mentioned the object mappings

Comment: Is it the whole message? Hibernate should specify what constraint failed on what entity.

Comment: i have added the whole message